# ASP.Net MVC Core - The instance of entity type '' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-5

I am new into using Entity Framework ASP.Net MVC Core. I am used to writing stored procedure and use call it for data manipulation such as CRUD functionality.

This is the code in the controller

```
  [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SaveHeight([FromBody] IEnumerable<VisitVitalSignInfo> height)
        {
            var errMsg = string.Empty;
            var triageId = 0;
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                        foreach (var item in height)
                        {
                            var heightData = _patient.GetVisitVitalSignInfoById(item.visitVitalSignInfoId);
                            if (heightData.visitVitalSignInfoId == 0)
                            {
                                _patient.AddVisitVitalSignInfo(item);
                               _patient.SaveVisitVitalSignList();
                               triageId = item.triageId;
                        }

                            else
                            {
                                _patient.UpdateVisitVitalSignInfo(item);
                                _patient.SaveVisitVitalSignList();

                        }
                        }



                    //_patient.AddVisitVitalSignInfo(height);
                    //_patient.SaveVisitVitalSignList();
                    //visitVitalSignInfoId = height.visitVitalSignInfoId;
                    ////_clinic.AddClinic(clinic);
                    ////_clinic.SaveClinicList();
                    ////clinicId = clinic.clinicId;
                }
                else
                    errMsg = "Invalid data!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errMsg = ex.Message;
            }
            return Json(new { errMsg = errMsg, triageId = triageId });
        }
```

To focus, the Update functionality is being called

```
_patient.UpdateVisitVitalSignInfo(item);
```

Here's the interface service

```
  public interface IPatientService
    {

        void AddVisitVitalSignInfo(VisitVitalSignInfo height);
        void UpdateVisitVitalSignInfo(VisitVitalSignInfo height);
    }
```

- i have removed other declaration there

here's the main service

```
 public void UpdateVisitVitalSignInfo(VisitVitalSignInfo height)
        {

            _visitVitaSignInfo.Update(height);
        }
```

the error appears after passing through the     _patient.UpdateVisitVitalSignInfo(item); in the controller

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this error before but I noticed that when you're checking the entity for existence by Id, you are assigning it to the `heightData` variable. However, when you're trying to do an update you are passing in `item` and not `heightData`. One way I have fixed this in the past is to assign the values from `item` to `heightData` and call

```
_patient.UpdateVisitVitalSignInfo(heightData);
_patient.SaveVisitVitalSignList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a small guess here, but I assume that you are updating a parent record and possibly adding children in that same call?  If so, you have to add the children first if you are doing an add with a PK for an identity field.  Otherwise, it will think you are working with the same entity twice instead of adding two new items.  If you can't do that, then you need to set the children's PK to -1, -2, etc first before calling save.  If you have multiple levels, then that PK reference needs to be updated for their children, too.